# Соединение сокетов двух языков программирования (lua + node)

Tags: node.js, сокет, lua

У меня есть сервер на NodeJS и lua-скрипт. Мне нужно реализовать подключение между ними. Я решил использовать сокет, но появилась серьезная проблема: сервер не видит подключение, когда клиент выдает сообщение об успешном подключении.

Сервер:

```js
var server = require('http').createServer((request, result) => {});
var socket = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
socket.on('connection', client => {
   console.log("New connection!");
})
```

Клиент:

```js
require("socket")
client = socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 3000)
if client then
    print("Connected!")
end
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что проверка socket.on будет выполнена при первом подключении к сокету? Что-то я в этом сомневаюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ваш сервер использует библиотеку socket.io, которая предоставляет набор костылей для допотопных браузеров, не знающих ничего о существовании вебсокетов. Честно говоря, не понимаю, почему вы выбрали её, а не чистые вебсокеты, но дело не в этом.

Дело в том, что существует огромная разница между **веб**сокетами, которые использует ваш сервер и TCP/UDP сокетами из lua-библиотеки "socket". Между ними нет совершенно ничего общего!

Вбейте в поисковик "lua websocket" и найдите какую-нибудь библиотеку для вашего клиента (я не буду давать конкретных ссылок, потому что не отвечаю за качество тех библиотек, которые найду).

Для nodejs есть проверенная временем библиотека, которую собственно использует сам socket.io - вот она https://github.com/websockets/ws.

Как вариант, вы также можете использовать UDP-сокеты в nodejs совместно с UDP-сокетами луа: https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html (в этом случае вам не понадобятся никакие сторонние библиотеки и у вас не возникнет проблемы с разницей в версиях протоколов, что очень вероятно при использовании вебсокетов от разных разработчиков).